# Количество div-ов в зависимости от количества значений в массиве на PHP

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Допустим, есть массив: значение1, значение2, значение3 
И мне нужен код, который будет генерировать div (пусть это будет ссылка xxx.yyy/zzz). Причём этих div-ов должно генерироваться несколько, в зависимости от количества значений в массиве. И в каждый div должно автоматически подставляться это значение (xxx.yyy/zzz/значение1; xxx.yyy/zzz/значение2 и так далее) 
Массив и подставление значений я примерно понимаю, как реализовать. Но не могу понять момент генерации количества div-ов в зависимости от количества значений в массиве 
По просьбе прописал код:

```
<div class="container">
<? $massive = array("значение1", "значение2", "значение3") ?>
<a href="xxx.yyy/zzz/'.$massive[0].'"></a>
<a href="xxx.yyy/zzz/'.$massive[1].'"></a>
<a href="xxx.yyy/zzz/'.$massive[2].'"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: покажите код так как понимаете - например для трех элементов. мы подскажем, как сделать цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Опираясь на ответ от Pashok](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1482330/498165), я допилил решение данной проблемы:
(там слишком много тегов и функция endforeach, из-за которых первоначальное решение у меня не работало)

```
<div class="container"> //Контейнер, в котором будут генерироваться div-ы
   <?
      $massive = array("значение1", "значение2", "значение3"); 
      /*В данном случае можно использовать только индексированные массивы,
      или массивы, где ключами являются только числа*/
      foreach($massive as $element) { //Запуск цикла
      /*$element - автоматически подставляемое значение из массива*/
         echo '<a href="xxx.yyy/zzz/'.$element.'"></a>'
      }
   ?>
</div>
```

По итогу получаем генерацию div-ов в количестве, равному количеству значений в массиве

Comment: Ну, если решение не работало из-за открытия/закрытия `foreach`, значит вы что-то пропустили :)

Comment: Возможно, не спорю

Answer (score 2):

Тут всё просто. Берём ваш массив и для каждого элемента ([foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)) делаем следующее:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php foreach($massive as $element): ?>
        <a href="xxx.yyy/zzz/<?= $element;?>"></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Если у вас значения хранятся не просто в массиве, а в [ассоциативном массиве](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/php/associative-arrays-php), то можно сделать следующее:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php foreach($massive as $element): ?>
        <a href="xxx.yyy/zzz/<?= $element['value']; ?>"></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Не стоить забывать, что:

> foreach работает только с массивами и объектами, и будет генерировать ошибку при попытке использования с переменными других типов или неинициализированными переменными

Иными словами: надо проверить ваш `massive` на существование, и если он не существует (неинициализирован), то пропускать вывод. Ну, или делать что-то другое.

```
<div class="container">
    <?php if(!empty($massive)): ?>
        <?php foreach($massive as $element): ?>
            <a href="xxx.yyy/zzz/<?= $element['value']; ?>"></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        some else
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what problem do you expect when using the following code  `foreach([] as $k) {}`

Comment: @splash58 Судя по всему, данный вывод будет где-то во view, где между началом и концом цикла может быть куда больше html-кода. А для этого проще будет использовать подобную конструкцию, чтобы не использовать в каждой строке `echo` и кучу кавычек

Comment: ой! теперь по-русски :) : почему надо пропускать foreach при пустом массиве - какие проблемы?

Comment: @splash58 Вот тут - да. Надо было написать `проверить на существование массива`, а не на пустоту

Answer (score 0):

> Но не могу понять момент генерации количества div-ов в зависимости от количества значений в массиве

А что тут понимать. Количество элементов в массиве узнаётся фукнкцией **[count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)**. Вот и всё. Дальше делается цикл от 0 до данного числа (точнее обычно  от `i=0` до `i<count`. То есть строго меньше), а внутри тела цикла делается всё, что необходимо

Comment: А я вот не понимаю) Бэкэнд слабо даётся

Comment: Работа с чем. С массивами. Нужно значить что? Количество......... Значит в первую очередь надо пойти в документацию в раздел массивы и посмотреть есть ли там функция которая даёт количество......... знание бэкенда для этого не требуется. Достаточно сопоставить то, что необходимо с тем, что есть в доках